# one-to-many with specific number in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, relationship

I'm build Reporting System. This system has 3 admins and each admin has 6 supervisors. I know that is one to many relationship but how to specify 1 admin to 6 supervisors in mysql. Thanks

Comment: Have an `admin` column in your supervisors table and set the ID of the admin?

Comment: You probably need to apply such constraints in your business logic.

Comment: @WilliamIsted yes I know I want to specify this number because what you said is exact one to many eelation

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply such constraints in your business logic, MySQL won't give you ability to apply such constraints.

If you are specifying supervisors for admin or admin for super visors, max limiting constraint should be implemented from your programming languages, or better yet, implement such logic in store procedures.